# How to get SVG text centered inside of its container instead of the whole page

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

So I'm making a photo frame designer using SVG. One of the features is that you can add your own text and it will appear on the frame. I'm using jQuery .keyup to do this. I want the text generated to appear central inside of the frame. Instead it seems to be center of the whole page or somewhere else.

Here is the URL of it for those who are interested or those wanting to see the full code: [frame designer](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2).

So here is the HTML/SVG code.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 1247.2 751.2" enable-background="new 0 0 1247.2 751.2" xml:space="preserve">
    <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1"
                    x1="0%" y1="0%"
                    x2="0%" y2="100%"
                    spreadMethod="pad">
    <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#FFEBCD" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#b29377" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <defs>                                  
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1246" height="1000">
            <image xlink:href="Images/frame2.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1247" height="751" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>             
    <defs>                                                              
        <pattern id="img3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1246" height="1000">
            <image xlink:href="Images/WALNUT.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1300" height="1300" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <defs>                              
        <pattern id="img5" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1246" height="1000">
            <image xlink:href="Images/pattern1.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1247" height="751" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect class="frame" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1247.2" height="751.2"/>
    <rect class="border" x="77.9" y="78.7" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1100" height="600"/>
    <path class="picture" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M748.8,441.5h-258c-4.7,0-8.5-3.8-8.5-8.5V175c0-4.7,3.8-8.5,8.5-8.5
    h258c4.7,0,8.5,3.8,8.5,8.5v258C757.3,437.7,753.5,441.5,748.8,441.5z"/>
    <path class="picture" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1051.3,441.5h-258c-4.7,0-8.5-3.8-8.5-8.5V175c0-4.7,3.8-8.5,8.5-8.5
    h258c4.7,0,8.5,3.8,8.5,8.5v258C1059.8,437.7,1056,441.5,1051.3,441.5z"/>
    <path class="picture" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M445.5,441.5h-258c-4.7,0-8.5-3.8-8.5-8.5V175c0-4.7,3.8-8.5,8.5-8.5
    h258c4.7,0,8.5,3.8,8.5,8.5v258C454,437.7,450.2,441.5,445.5,441.5z"/>
    <text class="text" transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 235 550.5599)" font-family="'ComicSansMS'" font-size="41.6368">Your words here</text>
    <line stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="751.2" x2="1247.2" y2="751.2"/>
    <line stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0.1" y1="0" x2="1247.4" y2="0"/>
    <line stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="751.2"/>
    <line stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="1247.4" y1="0" x2="1247.4" y2="751.2"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
width:831.5px;
height:500.8px;
display:inline-block; 
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right: auto;
float:left;
margin-left:100px;
margin-top:20px;
}

.text {
fill:white;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif, verdana;
text-align:center;
text-anchor: middle;
margin:auto;
}
```

and jQuery

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
    $('.text').html($(this).val());
    $('.text').css("text-anchor: middle", "center");
});
```

Comment: You could play around with the `x` and `y` of the `text` element, using the reference size from the `viewBox`.

Comment: Yeah although the text will always be getting longer and shorter so the values would have to be different each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the transform matrix for the text you need to make sure it's center point is the center of the container. If you want it to be centered you have to take half the container's width as the X translation and center the text (as you're already doing). This is a formula that's program language agnostic, so you can remember and use it in just about any scripting language. I used these values for the `transform` attribute (on your website via Firebug in Firefox) and it seems to have centered the text whenever I type:

```
transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 624.6 550.5599)"
```

This is what that looks like: http://cl.ly/image/0V1E382A2m3p

Leave your CSS on the text element as you have it and you can remove the jQuery on keyup as this takes care of making the text centered. That should solve the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. You were already very close to the solution on your own.